# How to pass a build number within the MultiJob plugin?

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

The [MultiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) is great and I want to use it for my build process, but there is one issue I have to solve before: There are three jobs A, B and C. SVN triggers job A and B (parallel execution) and job C starts when A and B have finished. Job C requires the artifacts from job A and B as an input.

```
          -> Job A (with A.zip) 
Trigger                          -> Job C (use artifacts A.zip and B.zip)
          -> Job B (with B.zip)
```

To design the workflow with the [MultiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) is easy, but I have no clue how to get the corresponding artifacts from job A and B in job C. Can I pass the build numbers to job C (buildNr(A) != buildNr(B))? Or is there a smarter way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The multijob plugin sets the following environment variables per job ([code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tikal-multijob-plugin/blob/0ce0d48edc7d1aa1824bf9b62b2366a02fdda014/src/main/java/com/tikal/jenkins/plugins/multijob/MultiJobBuilder.java#L822-L826)):

- `<JOBNAME>_BUILD_NUMBER`
- `<JOBNAME>_BUILD_RESULT`

Where `JOBNAME` is created by the name of the job with all non characters and numbers replaced with `_`. Thus you can pass the build numbers as parameters to Job C:

[image: configuration of job C with Jenkins MultiJob plugin]

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround using EnvInject and a groovy script:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20241

Comment: Great to see that there is more than one way to solve this issue! I used a modified version of the copyartifacts plugin instead (see my answer).